# How do I add an enum to the new console template in C# for Visual Studio 2022 for net6.0?

Tags: c#, templates, enums, visual-studio-2022

If I add an enum to the default code for a new c# Console App:

```
// See https://aka.ms/new-console-template for more information
enum testEnum
{
    one = 1,
    two = 2
}
Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
```

I get the following error on the Console.WriteLine line: 
**Error CS8803  Top-level statements must precede namespace and type declarations.**

Moving the enum to the bottom of the code fixes the error.
Is there a way to keep the enum at the top and get rid of the error?

Comment: Not when using top-level statements, which is what the compiler error is trying to tell you. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/69601663/43846

Answer (score 2):

As @stuartd said, you cannot declare an `enum` before using statements such as `Console.WriteLine()`. stackoverflow.com/a/69601663/43846 explains that you can still use the old form of Program.cs and then declare the `enum` in Program class before calling `Console.WriteLine()` in `main`.